# I18nManager.forceRTL doesn't applies changes in first app load

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an app that created by awesome **`React-native`** and my layout designed to be in RTL mode. I've set up an option for forcing the layout to be RTL but my option doesn't works in first app load after installing. This feature applies in second run.

I wrote this option in our index.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { I18nManager } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

I18nManager.forceRTL(true);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <MainStack />
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Seems to be a know bug: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11475

Does putting the rtl tag into your html doc not work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a week finally i found a logicly way to solve this issue with using  **`Redux`  & `react-native-restart`** plugin. I'm also use a nice splash screen to user don't show a restarting progress for this purpose.

So let's dive into code:

**Redux action:**

```
export const GET_APP_LAYOUT_DIRECTION = 'GET_APP_LAYOUT_DIRECTION';
export const SET_APP_LAYOUT_DIRECTION = 'SET_APP_LAYOUT_DIRECTION';

export const getAppLayoutDirection = () => ({
  type: GET_APP_LAYOUT_DIRECTION,
});

export const setAppLayoutDirection = direction => ({
  type: SET_APP_LAYOUT_DIRECTION,
  direction
});
```

**Redux Reducer:**

```
import {
    GET_APP_LAYOUT_DIRECTION,
    SET_APP_LAYOUT_DIRECTION,
} from '../actions/app';

const initialState = {
    layout: 'ltr',
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case GET_APP_LAYOUT_DIRECTION:
        return {
          ...state,
        };
      case SET_APP_LAYOUT_DIRECTION:
        return {
          ...state,
          layout: action.direction,
        };
      default:
        return state;
    }
};

export default reducer;
```

**Home Screen:**

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import RNRestart from 'react-native-restart'; // Import package from node modules
import { getAppLayoutDirection, setAppLayoutDirection } from '../actions/app';

class Home extends PureComponent {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);

     this.props.dispatch(getAppLayoutDirection());
     if(this.props.layout === 'ltr'){
       this.props.dispatch(setAppLayoutDirection('rtl'));
       RNRestart.Restart();
     }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
     if(this.props.layout && this.props.layout === 'rtl'){
        SplashScreen.hide();
     }
  }
} 

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { layout } = state.app;
  return {
    layout
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Home);
```

Answer (score 25):

I had the same problem and solved it by invoking `forceRTL` in `MainApplication.java` in the `onCreate` method.

```
...
import com.facebook.react.modules.i18nmanager.I18nUtil;

...
 @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);

    I18nUtil sharedI18nUtilInstance = I18nUtil.getInstance();
    sharedI18nUtilInstance.forceRTL(this,true);
    sharedI18nUtilInstance.allowRTL(this, true);
  }
...
```

On IOS add in the `AppDelegate.m`

```
...
NSURL *jsCodeLocation; // this probably already exists!
[[RCTI18nUtil sharedInstance] allowRTL:YES];
[[RCTI18nUtil sharedInstance] forceRTL:YES];
...
```

[Source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11475#issuecomment-377877404)

Comment: When I'm trying to implement it in `MainApplication.kt` it's throwing error

Answer (score 9):

I went through the same issue this helped me.
This is abit modified answer without the need to use redux.

First you check current state with `I18nManager.isRTL` then forceRTL if not and restart with [react-native-restart](https://github.com/avishayil/react-native-restart).

```
   constructor(props) {          
      //Force RTL
      if(!I18nManager.isRTL){
         I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
         RNRestart.Restart();
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that on iOS, next to having added all relevant RTL locales to your Xcode project (e.g. Arabic). You should also make sure that your .ipa contains .lproj folders for each locale. Otherwise iOS doesn't pick up on the supported languages.

This is a common issue in React Native projects where you don't typically write a lot of Swift/Obj-C code & most of the translations happen in JavaScript (apart maybe from some stuff in you Info.plist).

Comment: I want to force RTL in ios I add `[[RCTI18nUtil sharedInstance] allowRTL:YES];`  in `AppDelegate.m` but it does not work, any tips?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a known issue, although all were closed without solution…:

- [I18n.forceRTL is forcing rtl layout only on second app launch](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11475)
- [I18Manager is not forcing RTL on app launch but works when restarting the app.](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32509)
- [React Native Can't disable RTL before app launch (works only on second app launch)](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35922)

Ideally, this should be solved by the RN team.

In the meantime, a native module developed by the community could potentially solve this issue, but I dd not come across any.

Therefore, for now, you may want to reference the below code restarting the app whenever the layout change between LTR and RTL or vice versa is needed:
<sub>(uses `react-i18next` with `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage` and `react-native-restart`)</sub>

```js
export const setLanguage = async code => {
  const isNewLanguageRTL     = i18next.dir(code) === 'rtl';
  const isCurrentLayoutRTL   = I18nManager.isRTL;
  const isLayoutChangeNeeded = isCurrentLayoutRTL !== isNewLanguageRTL;

  if (!isLayoutChangeNeeded) {    // This check is performed because the app is
    i18next.changeLanguage(code); // going to be restarted anyway if an LTR/RTL
  }                               // layout change is needed.
  
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(ASYNC_STORAGE_LANG_KEY, code);

    if (isLayoutChangeNeeded) {               // Only if the `AsyncStorage` update was
      I18nManager.forceRTL(isNewLanguageRTL); // successful, since otherwise, the new
      RNRestart.restart();                    // language would not apply after restart.
    }
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error('Error setting language to AsyncStorage:', error);
  }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Thats because you should use I18nManager with try and catch!
it needs "await" to do his job.

```
try {
    I18nManager.allowRTL(false);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
```

use it like this, and it will work.